# forged pat no 70884 steel nail extractor

Tags: us708841

I have a 70884 nail extractor for over 64 years while growing up in

Columbia,Connecticut.  Is this different from the 708841?  Maybe a prototype?

And therefore more of an antique? If so what would it's value be?

Answer (score 1):

US patent 708841 is indeed for a nail extractor, the patent being granted in 1902.  The application number was 110073 (basically, granted numbers run sequentially, while application numbers restart every few years in the US).  US patent 70884 is completely unrelated, for a 'Hat and Coat Hook' and was granted in 1867.
Looking online at pictures of some Bridgeport nail pullers, the last digit of the patent number on the article does not look as deeply formed as the other digits. It's quite possible that the markings were stamped on the tool after it had been forged, and sometimes the impression is uneven.  I strongly suspect that the '1' was lightly formed and/or has been rubbed away.  Perhaps if you look closely you may see a trace of it.
Beyond that, I'm afraid valuation is beyond my sphere of ignorance. additionally patents are expired long back.